# Is there any way to find out and/or limit GPU usage by process in Windows?

Tags: windows, process, gpu, cpu-usage, gpgpu

I'd like to launch CPU and GPU intensive process on some machines, but these processes must not interfere with user's tasks. So I need to limit or at least detect GPU usage by my processes. These processes are closed-source, so I can't watch GPU usage from inside.

Comment: Actually, I meant programmatic way.

Comment: You can modify your original question and say programmatically

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your subject line question is: yes (On Windows Vista and up), use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) from Microsoft to monitor per process GPU usage. nvidia's [parallel nsight](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-parallel-nsight) can do this also. Now, the body of your question sounds like you want to do this remotely. Unfortunately I'm not aware of a way to do this remotely. Still, hopefully this will be of some use to you.

edit to add: If you fire up Process Explorer I don't think it shows the GPU stats by default, to get them right click on the list of columns and add them.

Comment: Actually, I meant programmatic way.

Answer (score -4):

The GPU is a resource that can only be used by one program at a time. If another process is using the GPU, then you can't get access to it.

A program may run multiple GPU kernels at the same time, but it's up to that program how those get run. There's no real concept of scheduling like there is with the OS and CPU processes.

Some vendors may have a way for you to check on the status of the device, like # cores in use, heat, fan speed, etc, but that won't let you change what's happening on it, and it will be specific to each vendor/device.

Comment: Are you sure GPU use is limited to only one process? If I launch 2 windows media players, each one will use VMR7 (or VMR9) renderer which is a DirectX based renderer that uses GPU.  Also WPF applications use hardware (unless you change registry settings) for all of their rendering.  You can definitely run more than one WPF app.

Comment: What is made is giving fractions of time for each program to talk with GPU, some parts of the job are parallel (the GPU can decode video while drawing a window, but there are specific moments, when this program communicates with the GPU (CPU <-> etc <-> GPU), that are not possible to happen in parallel (exactly at same time). Now, you may think, but this is scheduling... Yes, made by CPU... The GPU itself has no formal scheduler.